# Can someone explain why this diode is reverse biased?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

[image]

In this question, we are asked to draw a picture of this circuit with the switch closed and opened.

When the switch is closed, the diode is replaced by an open circuit. I understand that this would only happen if the output voltage is greater than the input voltage when the switch is closed, but how can we be sure that this is what occurs?

[image]

Comment: What happens to the voltage across the IGBT when it's turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transistor is on it shorts the inductor to ground, and so the diode is reversed biased because the capacitor has positive voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the diode with an ideal current source of 0A. Analyze the circuit to see what the voltage would be across the diode/current source. If you find that the voltage across the current source is greater than the assumed knee voltage of the diode then the diode must be forward biased.

Answer (score 0):

When the switch is closed, it is ideally short circuit to ground. Hence the current in coil will go into ground instead of going into the diode, also the voltage of the anode will be zero (ground). So no way it is going to be on, hence reverse-biased.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a "boost converter", a fairly standard design and you will be able to find loads out about it on YouTube or Google.

When the transistor is off, the voltage source will charge the inductor and capacitor and also power the resistor, because those are the only two ways for current from the voltage source to flow from the positive to the negative terminals.

When the transistor is on, the voltage source and inductor get shorted to the voltage source's negative terminal. The capacitor will no longer be charged by them, and begin to discharge across the resistor.

If the diode was not there, the current supplied by the capacitor would be able to flow back that way straight back to the negative terminal of the voltage source. Because it is there, it blocks this so that all of the capacitor's current flows through the resistor.